# android object/ class structure for graphing

Tags: java, android

Am currently developing an android application that requires real time data viewing with achartengine: still in the application design:

My data will be presented in two types:

1. plain data
2. charts - using achartengine
         in this category i will have several graph types like line chart, bar, pie e.t.c

The problem that am having when designing class diagrams for the application is that am stuck on whether to handle Graphs as a package then have the graph types as a class inside the package or create a class for each graph type which resides on my application package..

Kindly help me out on this.

Answer (score 1):

There are many options for packaging classes. Usually the basic advice is to follow the strategy of putting classes that will change together in the same package. An interesting discussion here : http://www.techrepublic.com/article/properly-package-your-java-classes/1049863.

Personally, I like to have a separate package for data structure classes and other packages that use them. It seems to me that it is easier to detect cycle dependencies when an application is organized this way.

The best reference I know is this one if you want to consider general design principles : http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod. The last 6 principles apply to package design.

Comment: Now have got u but still need more guidance on designing an android app coz this is my first time to develop a big android app.....     could somebody post to me any article that shows a step-by-step procedure in designing a big android app? right from the layered architecture design, context, uml diagrams to class diagrams

Comment: There is no unified architecture for android. Even, up to now, no one seems to have tackled this job of putting guidelines for that, neither google nor the community. Nevertheless, except a few android specific features, there is no real difference between an android application and a standalone one. You can design for performance, maybe more than in other environments, take more care of multithreading aspects, but still all the knowledge and experience you can put your hands on by reading design and architecture papers is valid for designing an android app.

Comment: You should not target a perfect design at first. Try to get inspired by common tutorials, common design patterns, common architecture advices and, as soon as you need some more robust architecture, redesign your app. Refactoring is definitely more interesting than targetting the right architecture from the beginning. With that in mind, read martin fowler refactoring advices on his website http://martinfowler.com/